# Symfony2 and Doctrine 2 result data incorrectly returns an array of nulls

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query I run in Doctrine; it now is failing, but in a weird way. This query has worked for a year, I just messed with my `composer.json` a bit by adding a couple new libraries, and changing some versions. I also updated my Linux box (maybe MySQL or MariaDB has been updated, not sure).

Whatever has changed (doubtful it's my bundle's Doctrine model code, unless it wasn't kosher in the first place and a core update now reveals it as broken), the query is now returning results, with an array of the correct amount of keys, however the values are getting NULLed somehow.  The array looks exactly like this, a direct copy and paste from the var_dump, e.g.

```
var_dump($query->getSql());
var_dump($results);
exit;

select GoalLabel from opt_goals where scale = 'mathematics'

array(17) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL [5]=> NULL [6]=> NULL [7]=> NULL [8]=> NULL [9]=> NULL [10]=> NULL [11]=> NULL [12]=> NULL [13]=> NULL [14]=> NULL [15]=> NULL [16]=> NULL }
```

But when I run this same query in MySQL command line, I get the actual results, which is the same amount of keys, but the values *are* there.

Here's the non default portion of my `composer.json` require section:

```
    "components/jquery": "~1.11,<2.0",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.3.*",
    "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "~2.1",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "~1.1",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~1.1",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "symfony/icu": "1.1.*",
    "mnot/hinclude": "dev-master",
    "rhumsaa/array_column": "~1.1",
    "webfactory/exceptions-bundle": "@stable",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.5",
    "hearsay/require-js-bundle": "~1.0",
    "browserstate/history.js": "dev-master"
```

Pay close attention to any version adjustments, because I did mess with this. However I don't know at which point Doctrine went off the deep end.

Edit: per the latest comments, and [now seeing this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2015/01/12/dbal-244-251.html), is this what is going on? Actually [this URL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_2_5.html) is more appropriate because I am not using `doctrine/dbal`, I'm using `doctrine/orm`.

Comment: instead `var_dump()` try `dump()` if you use `symfony +2.6` and lets see what you get.

Comment: Did you check the `EXPLAIN` in your web profiler?

Comment: no but thats a great idea, i dont have a profiler, this is a json response.  how would i do that?  i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555697/how-to-display-the-symfony-profiler-for-api-request-made-in-the-browser and trying the solution to add the service now

Comment: You can make the call to your JSON response with `app_dev.php/` prepended to the URI and then go through the history of your requests (see the "view last 10" at the top of every full-page profiler?)

Comment: using the search?  i havent done that before.  dont really knjow how to use the profiler, maybe because its primarily a json api.  SO to test what you suggested, i loaded the nulled results again, saw teh json, changed the url to /_profiler, that takes me to the search page, i click on search, leaving all criteria blank, an di only see one in there, thats the one i made a mistake on `/__profiler`, instead of `/_profiler`.  im only seeing this one profile.   do you think its not logging them, or am i doing this wrong?  i think its just not profiling it.

Comment: so dont i need to debug doctrine somehow?  this looks pretty damning for being able to use the profiler, answer 'nope' https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/bgWBKtXmxbM

Comment: Do You use Doctrine? It was update to 2.5 version. Try to use 2.4. Anyway I had some problems after doctrine update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem was caused by the updating of `doctrine/orm` to version 2.5 from 2.4.x. There is a lot of [BC breaks](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_2_5.html).

Downgrade your `doctrine/orm` to https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/orm#v2.4.7 and the problem will go away.  After knowing this is your issue, you need to rewrite your queries to satisfy any new requirements. I did see a note in there about MariaDB problem as well.

In fact, since I haven't tackled this fully yet myself, it might be as easy as regenerating the entities.  I'm always hesitant when I do that....

Answer (score 2):

Today I had to face this "issue". In my case, all was about null values in the column marked as @id. Let me show you.

This is invoices's table:

```
mysql> select * from payments;
+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+---------+
| transaction                      | date                | total | invoice |
+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+---------+
| JB2BJ43dqhI7xiVxP1j1ExlIbraplHiS | 2015-04-24 21:23:08 |   320 |       3 |
| DIavWPjtVf9ZJ0m4GBnP2ZDCBzV4PBmQ | 2015-04-24 21:49:39 |   320 |       4 |
| XporZAkdIFDbdq9Uzvw1rp2GD4W98esy | 2015-04-24 22:18:10 |   320 |       5 |
| OFgUCb5kdjftqiNUmU6BCok47EZ6Sw2X | 2015-04-27 01:10:01 |    25 |      10 |
+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+---------+
```

I added a new column in order to marked as a primary key:

```
mysql>alter table invoices add column `id_payment` int auto_increment;

mysql> select id_payment, transaction, date, total, invoice from paymen
s limit 4;
+------------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+--------+
| id_payment | transaction                      | date                | total | invoice|
+------------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+--------+
|       NULL | JB2BJ43dqhI7xiVxP1j1ExlIbraplHiS | 2015-04-24 21:23:08 |   320 |       3|
|       NULL | DIavWPjtVf9ZJ0m4GBnP2ZDCBzV4PBmQ | 2015-04-24 21:49:39 |   320 |       4|
|       NULL | XporZAkdIFDbdq9Uzvw1rp2GD4W98esy | 2015-04-24 22:18:10 |   320 |       5|
|       NULL | OFgUCb5kdjftqiNUmU6BCok47EZ6Sw2X | 2015-04-27 01:10:01 |    25 |      10|
+------------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+--------+
```

Now, in the `Invoice` model I set the new column as my primary key:

```
/**
 * @entity
 * @table(name="invoices")
 */
class Invoice
{
    /**
     * @id
     * @column(type="int", name="id_payment")
     */
    protected $id;

    // ...
```

When I altered the table, all values in `id_payment` column is null. This will return null values even all other fields contains information:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select(['a']);
$qb->from(Invoice::class, 'a');
$invoices = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
dd($invoices);
```

Result:

```
[
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
]
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I had the same problem and it saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you did a var_dump.

var_dump only displays the items in their current state as the objects themselves have not been populated yet. they get pulled on their first call if you lazy loaded them.

Comment: i dont think so, beacuse its a json app, if i simply pull the url, i get [null,null,null,null], this is how i noticed teh error in the first place.  then i put the debug stuff on there, and its showing me the same..  var_dump will show the correct result, however, because im var dumping the results ` $results = $query->getArrayResult();` so im not sure what you mean. `getResult()` yields same result.  so what you see in the snippet in the OP, is exactly whats returning, the first line is the $query->getSql(), and the 2nd line is the $results dump

Comment: lazy loading has nothing to do with "getting the results", but "using the results", for me the hint is still valid without a negative proof

and btw [the abstractquery execute method](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.AbstractQuery.html#575) caches queries, the best thing you can do is xdebug the code behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have @ORM\Id annotation in your entity!